# Intermittent network after upgrading to Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 server to 18.04.  Since doing that I've had a problem with networking being intermittent.  For example I'll ping google.com and receive maybe 8 of 25 packets sent. The response is reasonable (< 25ms) but I'm loosing a lot of packets.

This machine (bendersvr01) is a virtualbox host with 2 network cards (enp5s0 and enp6s0).  I run a virtual ubuntu 18.04 (also recently upgraded) server with Plex Media Server. From the virtual ubuntu server (mediasvr01) I can ping google.com and experience no packet loss.  The fact that I can ping from the virtual server should eliminate any cable, switch, router, etc issues.  Pinging anything local works fine. It must be a configuration issue in Ubuntu.  I really don't know where to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

Output from ping 8.8.8.8.....

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8  
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=16.8 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=15.3 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=14.2 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=22.0 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=122 time=15.7 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=34 ttl=122 time=13.5 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=122 time=13.4 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=36 ttl=122 time=15.5 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=122 time=12.3 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=38 ttl=122 time=13.1 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=39 ttl=122 time=16.6 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=40 ttl=122 time=13.9 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=41 ttl=122 time=15.2 ms  
^C  
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---  
69 packets transmitted, 13 received, 81% packet loss, time 69316ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.389/15.264/22.069/2.366 ms
```

Netstat shows I'm not actually dropping packets but still seeing the problem.

```
brad@BenderSVR01:~$ sudo netstat -i
[sudo] password for brad:
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp5s0    1500     2473      0      0 0          1270      0      0      0 BMRU
enp6s0    1500     4502      0      0 0          3182      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536    26783      0      0 0         26783      0      0      0 LRU
```

Comment: Anyone?  I'm pulling my hair out with this.

Comment: A bit more info.  I can ping the server (192.168.71.201) from other devices on my network and there are no packets being dropped.  It appears to be only when pinging outside of my network